# accessing object method obj-C

Tags: objective-c, oop

I have this object

Objectus.m

```
#import "Objetus.h"


@implementation Objetus

@synthesize stringa = _stringa;

- (id) init {

    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"zumba");
        self.stringa = @"ss9";

        //[self piraguense];
    }



    return  self;
}

- (void) piraguense {
    NSLog(@"cucu");
}

- (void)dealloc {

    [_stringa release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

So  my question is how to acces the method "piraguense"

```
Objetus *instaObjetus = [[Objetus alloc]init];

    NSLog(@"instaObjetus ::%@", instaObjetus);

    NSLog(@"propiedad del objetus::%@ ", instaObjetus.stringa);

    instaObjetus.piraguense ; //warning
```

as this `instaObjetus.piraguense`
gives me a warning,

Comment: You are not advised to call a method using ***dot syntax*** unless it is is getter/setter of a ***@property***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for calling a method* is:

```
[instaObjetus piraguense]
```

*or, in Objective C terms **send message to an instance**

Comment: awesome thanks!, so obvious, so the dot notation doesnt call methods?, just properties?, thanks!

Comment: Well, technically, you can use dot notation with any object, and, in fact you can invoke a method like you would in C#, using blocks. Here's a small paste bin of an example: http://ideone.com/K8Rs7

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you have a look at this cheat sheet if you are lazy about reading all the reference documents.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/downloads/RW-Objective-C-Cheatsheet.pdf